# How can I use a local method variable in a totally different method?

Tags: java, android, methods

I have a method written like this...

```
public void getRequest(String Url) {

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            Toast.makeText(MenuUtama.this, request(response) ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
}
```

I need to be able to access the local variable `request` in another method, so that I can call `request.response`. How am I able to access this local method from a totally different method?

Comment: How is request(response) a variable ??

Comment: `request(response)` in your snip-it is not a variable. What is it that you are trying to achieve as various options exist but could have problems with thread-safety or the like.

Comment: As aij and radimpe pointed out, request(response) is not a variable.  Anyways if you want to refer a variable from other methods then you make that variable as an instance variable, like declare it in the class outside any block.

Comment: On a separate issue, why are you running this code in the Android UI thread? This will make your app unresponsive until the HTTP command has finished executing. You should be running this on a totally separate Thread.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the scope of variables of response and and request,I mean declare these variable at class level not in method level.

Comment: The code snip-it suggests that the OP wants to run this in a multi-threaded environment. Wouldn't saving something like a `request` into a class variable cause problems?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call any variable declare as a local variable inside any function. you can do that in a way as follows

```
public class A{
    HttpGet request;
        HttpResponse response;
    void methodA(){
          request = //........
           response = //...........
    }
    void methodB{
        //here you can refer to request and response as they are the instance variables of the class.
    }
}
```

If you want to access those from outside the class, then you have to create an object of **class A** and then call as follows

```
A a = new A();
//now you can call a.request or a.response
```

But remember the variables access specifiers should allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something along these lines:

```
protected Object myRequest;

public void getRequest(String Url) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                myRequest = request(response);
                Toast.makeText(MenuUtama.this, myRequest, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Obviously change `Object` to whatever class `request(response)` works out to be, rename `myRequest`, and preferrably use accessors on a private instance variable rather than making it protected and assigning directly, but you get the point, hopefully, that you need an instance variable to hold the value of your method call `request(response)`.

Answer (score 0):

you should declare your `response` variable in a class-level scope. here's your code.

```
public class YourClass{

    //Declare your request varible in a class-level scope
    //so it can be accessed by any method
    HttpGet request;


    public void getRequest(String Url) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    response = client.execute(request);
                    Toast.makeText(MenuUtama.this, request(response) ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void otherMthod(){
        System.out.println(request); //request variable is accessible in this scope.
    }
}
```