# Accessing an array from a different method

Tags: java

I am trying to access and store information in the array 'qmissed' from the method 'questionsMissed', how would i do that?

Thank you for your help!

```
public class DriverExam {

    public void makeMissedArray(){

        int smissedarray = totalIncorrect();
        int[] qmissed = new int[smissedarray];
    }



    public int[] questionsMissed(){
        if(totalIncorrect() > 0){
            makeMissedArray();
        }

        int x = 0;
        if(totalIncorrect() == 0){
            return qmissed;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            if(correct[i] != student[i]){
                qmissed[x] = (i+1);
                x++;
            }
        }
        return qmissed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass it to the method or make it an instance level field

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use a local method variable in a totally different method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919347/how-can-i-use-a-local-method-variable-in-a-totally-different-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want `qmissed` to be an instance variable:

```
public class DriverExam {
    int[] qmissed;

    public void makeMissedArray(){

        int smissedarray = totalIncorrect();
        qmissed = new int[smissedarray];
    }
    ...
}
```

There will be one copy of `qmissed` for each instance of the DriverExam class, and it can be accessed by any instance method of the class.